# AVG only valid dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple search query like this one:

```
 SELECT COUNT(id),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN nation = 'german' THEN 1 END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN nation = 'french' THEN 1 END),

        AVG(AGE(birthday))

 FROM persons;
```

My problem is that I get an error:

```
  ERROR: date out of range for timestamp
```

I suppose I get this error because not every `person` has a `birthday` saved.

`birthday` is a `date-field`

**How can I prevent this error, and only average birthdays that are valid dates?**THANKS

Comment: Would those records be excluded from the entire result set or just the average?

Comment: @DStanley only the average!

Comment: The *date-field* is not a type in PostgreSQL. The `age()` function accepts `timestamp`(s), so I suspect, that your field is just `text` or `varchar` & the automatic type conversion cannot convert invalid dates.

Comment: You must provide your version of Postgres and the table definition (`\d persons` in psql). Ideally some test data and the desired result, too.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN nation = 'german' THEN 1 END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN nation = 'french' THEN 1 END),

        AVG(AGE(COALESCE(birthday, 0) ))

 FROM persons where birthday is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks, but Got Same Error,

Comment: @JohnSmith:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: But then the zeroes might seriously bias the average!   Just add a "WHERE birthday IS NOT NULL" where clause.

Comment: By excluding people without valid birthdays the counts would be incorrect, even though the average might be better.

Answer (score 1):

I would use another case statement to exclude the invalid null values from the `avg(age())` calculation:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(id),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN nation = 'german' THEN 1 END),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN nation = 'french' THEN 1 END),
  AVG(CASE WHEN birthday IS NOT NULL THEN AGE(birthday) END)
FROM persons;
```

If you were to add a `where birthday is not null` clause the average would be correct (or as correct as it can be) but the counts would be off due to the excluded rows not being counted.

See this [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/79c75/2) and notice how the counts differ between the two queries.

Comment: Your answer seems correct! But i still get the error `ERROR: date out of range for timestamp` seems like there is wrong data in the database! What can I do ?

Comment: Hmm, I would guess that there might be an invalid value in the birthday column - can't really help you on that. Try ordering by birthday and look at the highest/lowest values to see if anything looks odd.

Comment: How could I check in the avg that the age is between 0 and 100 years maybe this would solve it! Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith `avg(case when birthday is not null and extract(year from AGE(birthday)) between 0 and 100 then AGE(birthday) end)`

Comment: @JohnSmith The timestamp data type has a range from 4713 BC to 294276 AD so I really doubt that you have any value outside the range, but just to be sure try running a `select id, age(birthday) from persons where birthday is not null` to see if it throws the same error.

Comment: @jwp Seems like I have one that is invalid! I did what you said but got the same error with invalid time stamp! Maybe I cannot pass a date to age?

Comment: @JohnSmith What data type is the birthday column?

Comment: @JohnSmith Run the query `SELECT extract( year from birthday) FROM persons where birthday is not null order by extract( year from birthday);` and look at the first and last values - are they in the range I described above?

Comment: When I try this! I get the same error! ERROR: date out of range for timestamp

Comment: @JohnSmith Obviously there's at least one value that PG can't convert to a timestamp using the datestyle setting you have, the only recommendation I can give you is to try finding the invalid value by running the query above on a subset of the data (using a range based on id perhaps) until you find it. Using a binary search approach it shouldn't take long to find it.